# NSLog writing data into sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, nslog

In my iOS application after I open sqlite to change data NSLog is occasionally writing messages into the database causing corruption to occur and making the app unusable. Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening? I would like to keep the NSLog statements in the code for debugging if possible.

Comment: Can you post some code where this is happening? Unless you are telling it to insert something into the database, it shouldn't insert anything.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior, it seems to be happening when logging in applicationWillResignActive.

Comment: I also have same issue. I think the problem can come from many connection to DB at same time, but i don't understand cause why, however My resolve removed all NSLog. Please let me know if it worked for you.